# How to fix width and height of a p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

In my web application i want to fix height and width of a PrimeFaces `p:dialog` in the way in which the dialog appears exactly in the middle of my web page, and if one want to minimize the window then the dialog should also be minimized.

I mean middle of my one of the frame not whole window. For example dynamic sized dialog like % width and height.

Comment: Primefaces now has a Dialog container that can be minimized as can be seen here - https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog.xhtml?jfwid=f83a4

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use following code to make it of fixed dimension:

```html
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" width="300" height="200">  
    <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />  
</p:dialog>
```

and to make minimize functionality. You can play with JavaScript to get it done.

**See Also**

- [PrimeFaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog.xhtml)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use a attribute `style` (or `styleClass`):

```html
<p:dialog ... modal="true" style="width:50% !important; height:40% !important; top:25% !important; left: 30% !important;">
  <!-- any components -->
</p:dialog>
```

See more [here](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/dialog).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using p-dialog, then you will want to use the built-in styleClass attribute.

```css
.my-style-class {
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<p-dialog styleClass="my-style-class"><p-dialog>
```

Comment: This question is about PrimeFaces, not PrimeNG

Comment: I'm aware, but since this is the top Google search for p-dialog as well, I thought I'd let people know in case they look here.

Comment: You could ask a new question and answer it (Q&A style) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to make it of fixed dimension,

```html
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" width="300" height="200">  
    <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />  
</p:dialog>
```

and to make minimize functionality. you can play with javascript to get it done.