# fix width and height of p:tabView primefaces

Tags: primefaces, tabs, scroll, height, tabview

I have this `p:tabView`

```
<p:tabView id="monpanel"  >

            <p:tab id="tab1" title="Informations">
                <ui:include src="includes/Informations.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="tab2" title="Prix">
            <ui:include src="includes/Prix.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="tab3" title="Fournisseurs">
            <ui:include src="includes/fournisseurs.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="tab4" title="Stock">
            <ui:include src="includes/stock.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>
```

and I want to fix the height and width to all tabs and when the width of one of them change because of the validation : all of them get the same width

and also I want to know if it is possible to make scrollbar inside `p:tabView`

*************************** *solution :* **********************************

```
<p:tabView id="monpanel">

            <p:tab id="tab1" title="Informations">
                <p:scrollPanel style="width: 596px;height: 231px;border: none;" mode="native" >
                    <ui:include src="includes/Informations.xhtml" />
                </p:scrollPanel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="tab2" title="Prix">
                <p:scrollPanel style="width: 596px;height: 231px;border: none;" mode="native" >
                    <ui:include src="includes/Prix.xhtml" />
                </p:scrollPanel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="tab3" title="Fournisseurs">
            <p:scrollPanel style="width: 596px;height: 231px;border: none;" mode="native" >
                <ui:include src="includes/fournisseurs.xhtml" />
                </p:scrollPanel>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab id="tab4" title="Stock">
            <p:scrollPanel style="width: 596px;height: 231px;border: none;" mode="native" >
                <ui:include src="includes/stock.xhtml" />
                </p:scrollPanel>
            </p:tab>



        </p:tabView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your scrollpanel inside your tabview, you can specify the mode to be 'native' to get this to work. See [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20004) for an example. Refer to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580443/how-to-fix-width-and-height-of-primefaces-dialogbox) regarding width and height.